# Image saved in NSDocumentDirectory is gone when update the App from App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, file, nsdocumentdirectory

The Image is saved as following codes:

```
-(NSString *)saveImage:(UIImage *)image withName:(NSString *)name{
    [self createDataPath];
    NSString *filePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);
    [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    return filePath;
}

-(void)createDataPath{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    dataPath = [[[paths objectAtIndex:0]
                stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyPhotos"]
            stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageUniqueId];

    /* check for existence of cache directory */
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]) {
        return;
    }

    NSError *error;

    /* create a new cache directory */
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath
                               withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                attributes:nil
                                                     error:&error]) {
    //URLCacheAlertWithError(error);
    return;
    }
 }
```

As I know the Image saved in the NSDocumentDirectory will not be cleaned when the App updated from App Store, but the fact is these images are gone. What's going on here?

Comment: What is `imageUniqueId` ?

Comment: @MidhunMP A random string

Comment: How did you retrieve those images ?

Comment: @MidhunMP myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myImagePath]];

Comment: From where did you get the myImagePath, because in your path contains a random string. Then how did you take that path ?

Comment: @MidhunMP the path is stored in the coredata

Comment: Are you storing the full path or CoreData?

Comment: @luyuan: that's the issue. When you update your app the data in the document directory will be there, but the name of application folder will be renamed. So your code won't work. It's better to save the unique folder name and use the NSFileManager to find the data using this information

Comment: Are you sure, you have updated the app, without deleting it? Updating app will never remove any thing, while deleting and downloading new app will remove all the data..

Comment: Then definitely it is the image you saved by some name, doesn't exist in your database, or, something.. You can test the behavior on simulator, by checking the documents directory, by running the old project, then running the new project make sure the app-id are same in both the projects.. All the best